# Toggling table rows - how to close all open rows

Tags: jquery

I'm working with a table as I'm pulling a lot of data from a database - so a lot more rows that the few in the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/43rdworld/8tv7rodL/7/).  My intent is to show some basic information in a visible row, while hiding more detailed info in another row.  Click on the 'More' link and the hidden row with the additional data becomes visible.

I've got the hidden rows toggling properly but really want to open only one row and close the others - and am stuck on how to accomplish that.  I've been looking at different examples for a while now and have not been able to successfully integrate anything I've found into the code I have and could use some help.

Many thanks in advance.  As mentioned earlier - [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/43rdworld/8tv7rodL/7/) and code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table.tctAdmin, .tctAdmin tr th {font-family:arial;font-size:9pt;border:1px solid #aaa;border-collapse:collapse;}
        .tctAdmin tr td {border:1px solid #ccc;border-collapse:collapse;}
        .tctAdmin tr th {font-size:1.1em;background-color:#ccc;}
        .tctAdmin tr td {padding:2px 5px 0 5px;}
        .tctAdmin tr td:nth-child(1) {width:17%;}
        .tctAdmin tr td:nth-child(2) {width:13%;}
        .tctAdmin tr td:nth-child(3) {width:13%;}
        .tctAdmin tr td:nth-child(4) {width:22%;}
        .tctAdmin tr td:nth-child(5) {width:16%;}
        .tctAdmin tr td:nth-child(6) {width:5%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tctAdmin">
    <tr>
        <th>Register Date</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Email Sent</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1/2/2015</td>
        <td>Fred</td>
        <td>Derf</td>
        <td>fderf@derf.com</td>
        <td>1/2/2015</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="editRecord">More</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tcm0" class="record">
        <td colspan="8">test 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1/3/2015</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>User</td>
        <td>tuser@user.com</td>
        <td>1/3/2015</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="editRecord">More</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tcm1" class="record">
        <td colspan="8">test 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1/7/2015</td>
        <td>Fearless</td>
        <td>Freep</td>
        <td>ffreep@bugsco.com</td>
        <td>1/7/2015</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="editRecord">More</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tcm2" class="record">
        <td colspan="8">test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1/12/2015</td>
        <td>Barney</td>
        <td>Rubble</td>
        <td>brubble@bedrock.gov</td>
        <td>1/12/2015</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="editRecord">More</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tcm3" class="record">
        <td colspan="8">test 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.record').hide();
        $('a.editRecord').click(function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil(":not(.record)").toggle('slow');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just add `$('.record').hide()` to click function and e to callback `function(e)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please take a look the below fiddler solution

```
$('.record').hide();
$('a.editRecord').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.record').hide();  
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil(":not(.record)").toggle('slow');                
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8tv7rodL/11/